# Cannot locate elements using selenium

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

Hi I have tried to input the username and password using selenium chromedriver but it always throws me unable to locate elements. I tried id, name, xpath, full xpath but none seems to work. I am trying to access this website: https://www.absolutecyclesingapore.com/reserve#/login

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();

driver.get('https://www.absolutecyclesingapore.com/reserve#/login').then(async function(){  
    await driver.sleep(5000)
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('username')).sendKeys('usertest')
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('password')).sendKeys('passwordtest')
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gone through your link. There are iframes in DOM and username password element are present in iframe.
You have to switch to iframe using xpath=(//iframe)[1].
Then try your code

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('username')).sendKeys('usertest')
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('password')).sendKeys('passwordtest')
```

Comment: Hi @Nitin Hambir, how do you know I have to switch frames?

Comment: It is simple, whenever if element is located by your xpath or any other locator strategy  in development tool but not identified when you run automation script. it means that element might be present in iframe or other locator strategy we have to use.